# Nginx reverse proxy on docker and unloaded assets

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I want to have my blog (powered by Ghost) served through Docker and accessible by the URL `cv.totem.io/blog`.

The problem is that URL aren't corrects. 
For relatives URL : 
`<script src="/ghost/ghost.js?v=b0685c4e1f"></script>`
And for absolutes :
`<link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost:2368/">`

It seems that it's a problem of configuration of the Docker container  for the absolute URL and a problem from Nginx for the relatives.

Here is my Nginx configuration :

```
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name cv.totem.io;
        rewrite ^(.*) http://$host$1 permanent;
}

upstream blog {
        server 127.0.0.1:7070;
        keepalive 8;
}

server {
        server_name www.cv.totem.io cv.totem.io;

        location / {
                root /var/www/totem/curriculum;
                index index.html index.htm;
        }

    location /blog {
                proxy_pass http://blog/;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

The [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/ghost/) has been freshly installed through this command :

`docker run --name some-ghost -p 7070:2368 -d ghost`

Answer (score -1):

You have to include /blog in the URL's to match 'location /blog' block in nginx.

Change the URL's as below:

```
<script src="/blog/ghost/ghost.js?v=b0685c4e1f">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost:2368/blog">
```